# projeto react-native nao funciona no celular e nem no emulador comando react-native run-android ao ser executado aparece este erro abaixo

Tags: react-native

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Erros abaixos:
:\meuApp\smartMoney>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
O sistema n�o pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

```
at makeError (C:\meuApp\smartMoney\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\meuApp\smartMoney\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\meuApp\smartMoney\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\meuApp\smartMoney\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

por favor alguem me ajude estou a tres dias nao consigo resolverja instalei tudo denovo e nada

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de que esteja fazendo tudo corretamente:
Primeiro faça o build no android-studio para verificar o projeto.
Depois vá ao seu terminal e na pasta do seu projeto entre na pasta android:

> cd android

Após entrar, digite o seguinte comando

> ./gradlew installDebug

e aguarde.

Não esqueça de rodar a aplicação no android-studio anteriormente.

Comment: Ruan Duarte,  desculpe amigo mais sou novo nesse ambiente de desenvolvimento e estou no começo de tudo ainda nos estudo oque voce quer dizer com fazer "BUILD"?

Comment: Abre o android-studio e carregue seu projeto, automaticamente ele ira fazer o build, espere dar a resposta de sucesso e prossiga para o terminal

Comment: ixi parceiro nao deu certo o cmd nao reconhece este comando coloquei uma foto pra ver melhor os erros